# Add headings to the column data in csv file linux

Tags: linux, shell, awk, sed

```
t_apps=`cat $output1 | awk '{print $2,$3,$4}'| uniq | wc -l`
t_instances=`cat $output1 | wc -l`
r_apps=`cat $output4 | awk '{print $2,$3,$4}'| uniq | wc -l`
n_apps=`cat $output5 | awk '{print $2,$3,$4}'| uniq | wc -l`
n_instances=`cat $output2 | wc -l`
d_instances=`cat $output3 | wc -l`
echo "$time,$t_apps,$n_apps,$r_apps,$t_instances,$n_instances,$d_instances" | sed 's/,/  /g' | >> /tmp/c_data.csv
```

trying to add static headings to the file c_data.csv.

Can any one please help.

for example

data in csv file coming like,

> 20 30 100 230

i want to add heading to the column data like

> tapp napp rapp tinstances
>
> 20    30  100   250

After update to the csv file data should be like, column heading should be static

> tapp napp rapp tinstances
>
> 20    30  100   250
>
> 21    35  150   100

Comment: Good that you have shown your code efforts,only thing is wrap your samples and codes into CODE TAGS and let us know then.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  echo "tapp napp rapp tinstances"
  echo "20 30 100 250"

  # replace this line with your code
  echo "21 35 150 100"
} | column -t > data.csv
```

`| column -t` is used to format the columns in a table format. Remove it if you don't need it.

Comment: If I write echo two times that will print heading again if I run the script. But i don't want to print heading again by using same script. Only want update column data with same script (same script run many times).

Comment: You don't. The line you replace _is_ your script and what I wrote is your second script: `{ echo "headline..."; ./script.sh; } | column -t > data.csv` or `{ echo "headline..."; ./script.sh | tail -n+3; } | column -t > data.csv` if you need to replace the first two lines.